# Cabinets in USA (presidential) and UK (parliamentary) system difference?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, congress, government, political-system

What differences are there in the way the cabinets work between the UK, with their parliamentary system, and the USA, with their presidential system?

Comment: I am going to say that the answer is yes, but the differences will deepened on which country you are talking about as not all parliamentary systems operate under the same rules.

Comment: The US isn't simply a presidential system.  The President is head of both state and government.  Many other countries have these two offices separated, with the cabinet going with the Prime Minister, not with the President.  In the case of the US, the cabinet is chosen by the President from anywhere, whereas in other countries the cabinet is usually chosen from the elected representatives or senate.

Comment: @RayButterworth Those in which the President and PM are separate are not “Presidential”. They are Parliamentary (e.g. Germany) or Semi–Presidential (e.g. France).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of no difference that strongly correlates with presidential vs. parliamentary systems. In a presidential system the cabinet members might be more likely to serve at the pleasure of the president and not the parliament, but that is not exclusively so.

Comment: The key differences between UK and US cabinet is that the UK government ministers (the most senior of whom are in the cabinet) are selected from amongst parliamentarians (as is the PM of course) rather than being outside appointees. This is not universal among parliamentary systems.

(Ministers can come from the House of Lords and sometimes people are given a peerage just so they can join the governmenet)
Strictly the UK cabinet it is subcommitee of the Privy Council chaired by the PM who is 'primus inter pares' (first among equals) though generally the PM has enough power to control it.